# Loading Laravel Model with hasMany relation data

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have two models:

```
class Parent extends Model {
    public function children(){
        return $this->hasMany(Child::class);
    }
}

class Child extends Model {
    public function parent(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Parent::class);
    }
}
```

When I run the following:

```
$parent = Parent::with(Child::class)->find(1);
```

I get the following error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::child()
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Have you tried $parent = Parent::with('children')->find(1) ? You can then loop on $parent->children in the result.

Comment: I should add that the table and column names are upper case and the model snippets I shared did not indicate this.  @ManuelArwedSchmidt running that results in this error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::CHILDREN()